# neuralnet:ANN results not reproducible even after setting seed

Tags: r

In nutshell will explain the code;
Am trying to forecast by creating 24 hourly models in a single day and collating the results in the data frame.Basic issue is not able to reproduce #the output even after setting seed.Please anyone help me.some custom functions #and objects i have made and there is no randomization in them.(Just FYI).

```
f <- as.formula("actual~ lag.1 + last3.avg+monsoon+mon.thurs+wdaySaturday+wdaySunday+holiday
      ")    #Defining the formula for neural network
    require(dplyr);require(neuralnet)
        set.seed(123456)
        nnet.hour=data.frame()#Initializing a dataframe
        #k=0
        #x=list()
        for(i in 1:24){#Running it for 24 hours in a day
          sub<-new.day.ahead[new.day.ahead$hour==i,]
          sub$lag.1<-lag(sub$actual,1)
          for(i in 1:nrow(sub)){
            sub$last3.avg[i]=sum(lag(sub$actual,1)[i],lag(sub$actual,2)[i],lag(sub$actual,3)[i],na.rm=TRUE)/3
          }

          ind=which(sub$mod.date==ymd(t[1]));ind#t[1] is basically a date #initialisation,getting the index
          monsoon=as.factor(sub$Monsoon.Dummy)
          wday=as.factor(sub$wday.dummy)
          holiday=as.factor(sub$holiday)
          sub=as.data.frame(cbind(sub[,c(4,16,17)],cbind(
            monsoon=model.matrix(~monsoon)[,-1],
            wday=model.matrix(~wday)[,-1],
            holiday=model.matrix(~holiday)[,-1]
          )))
          names(sub)[5]<-"mon.thurs"
          ##Normalising the data for training in a neural net 
          sub[,2][1]=0
          maxs <- apply(sub, 2, max) 
          mins <- apply(sub, 2, min)

          scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(sub, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
          train<- scaled[1:I(ind-1),]
          test<- scaled[ind,]

          set.seed(123456)
          nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train,hidden =7,linear.output = TRUE)
          pr.nn<-neuralnet::compute(nn,test[,-1])
          #Normalising back
          pr.nn.<- pr.nn$net.result*(max(sub$actual)-min(sub$actual))+min(sub$actual)
          test.r <- (test$actual)*(max(sub$actual)-min(sub$actual))+min(sub$actual)


          u=mape(as.numeric(test.r),as.numeric(pr.nn.));u#Calculating Mean Absolute Percentage Error
          if(i==1){

            nnet.hour=data.frame(actual=as.numeric(test.r),forecast1=as.numeric(pr.nn.),mape=u)
          }else{

            nnet.hour=rbind(nnet.hour,data.frame(data.frame(actual=as.numeric(test.r),forecast1=as.numeric(pr.nn.),mape=u)))
            nnet.hour=data.frame(nnet.hour)
          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide test data?

Comment: @sebastianmm That i  Can't but i just want  to freeze the randomization which somehow i am not able to freeze.

Comment: Have you checked if the nn objects are the same? The only thing randomized in the neuralnet function, as far as I know, is the initialization of weights.

Comment: Yes ,haven't checked the nn objects but they will be different as the predictions they are giving are different.even for the same sort of code where i use random forests for prediction ,output isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.This is solved.Actually for some iterations I failed to invoke 'dplyr' package  ,so the lag variables i was creating using lag(function 'lag' is both in base as well  as dplyr package) function were returning just the same series as the variable I was trying to forecast courtesy which errors were ~negligible.
Once I invoke dplyr package Results are reproducible.

Thanks.